# Finding the best case and worst case performance time for the code

Tags: python

```
def sorting(seq):
    prev = seq[0]
    conf = True
    for itr in seq:
        if itr < prev:
            conf = False
            break
        prev = itr
    if conf: return seq
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        j = i
        while j>0 and seq[j]<seq[j-1]:
            seq[j],seq[j-1]=seq[j-1],seq[j]
            j = j-1
    return seq
```

Can someone tell me how I could find the best case and worst-case performance time for the above code?

Comment: yes you can, run it and profile it!

Comment: Best case would be when it is already sorted. And worst case would be when the input is reverse sorted. Use the two inputs to profile the code. (Unless you're looking for the Big-O complexity, in which case, read up on the algorithm used.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def sorting(seq):
    prev = seq[0]
    conf = True
    for itr in seq:
        if itr < prev:
            conf = False
            break
        prev = itr
    if conf: return seq
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        j = i
        while j>0 and seq[j]<seq[j-1]:
            seq[j],seq[j-1]=seq[j-1],seq[j]
            j = j-1
    return seq
```

the best case is clearly when the list is already sorted
which you can see goes through the list once  so (O(n))

the worst case is when the list is in reverse order
which is O(n^2)  (I think at least)